# How to change TScrollBox horizonal scrollbar size (width or height) in Delphi under Windows 10?

Tags: delphi, windows-10, scrollbar, tscrollbox

I want to change the `TScrollBox` scrollbar size - I was using this:

```
Uses
  CommCtrl;
....
  InitializeFlatSB(Scrollbox1.handle);
  FlatSB_SetScrollProp(Scrollbox1.Handle, WSB_PROP_CXVSCROLL, 10, true);
```

...but I think that it's not working anymore with Windows 10.

Comment: If you look at the remark in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-flatsb_setscrollprop , it says *Note  Flat scroll bar functions are implemented in Comctl32.dll versions 4.71 through 5.82. Comctl32.dll versions 6.00 and higher do not support flat scroll bars.* which confirms your thoughts.

Comment: It is possible to use multiple versions of ComCtrl32 at the same time. It would take some bit of manual work, but for instance you could derive a new class from `TScrollBox` and override its `CreateWindowHandle()` method to create its `HWND` within a separate [Activation Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/activation-contexts) that uses an older ComCtrl32. This way, the rest of your app can continue to use ComCtrl32 v6 for everything else.

Comment: you right @RemyLebeau , actully i have seen this soultion over the forums , its seems to be the only sloution for what i want .